# Данные не записываются в БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Я создала БД "anastasiya" c таблицей "users".

При регистрации пользователя на сайте, в таблицу "users" ничего не записывается. Проверка на кол. символов "логина" и "пароля" проходит успешно. Ошибок никаких не выдает.

**Подскажите, что здесь может быть не так?**

Вот код:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['reg'])){
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $bad=false;
        session_start();
        unset ($_SESSION['error_login']);
        unset ($_SESSION['error_password']);
        unset ($_SESSION['reg_success']);
        if ((strlen($login) < 3) || (strlen($login) > 32)){
            $_SESSION['error_login'] = 1;
            $bad=true;
        }
        if ((strlen($password) < 6) || (strlen($password) > 32)){
            $_SESSION['error_password'] = 1;
            $bad=true;
        }
        if (!$bad){
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","anastasiya");
            $password = md5($password);
            $login = $mysqli->real_escape_string($login);
            $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

            $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO users ('login','password')VALUES('$login','$password')");
            $mysqli -> close();
            $SESSION['reg_success'] = 1;
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Опустив то, что подобный код писать вообще нельзя, предположу, что не включен автокоммит и надо его включить или отправить `commit` вручную

Comment: И кстати, если так писать то в БД по идее должны сохраниться как раз строки `'$login'` и `'$password'` вместо введенных пользователем. Поэтому либо используйте конкатенацию строк, либо смотрите как в mysqli передавать параметры (я, к сожалению с mysqli не знаком).

Comment: @Anastasiya думаю вам будет полезно ознакомится http://it.onat.edu.ua/docs/WEB_PHP_the_right_way.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `$mysqli = new mysqli` написать

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

из сообщения об ошибке видно, что имена полей в запросе указаны как строки, в кавычках. Имена полей должны писаться без кавычек.

Для этого запроса обратные кавычки не нужны. Но сделать её можно нажав одновременно клавишу shift и клавишу ~ (Ё в русской раскладке)

Comment: А подскажите еще. Я добавила строку которую Вы мне сказали. И получила ошибку  Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''login','password') VALUES('jhsjdh','4461c833488ae207959654afb5e4a98c')' at line 1' in Z:\home\Anastasiya\www\reg.php:25 Stack trace: #0 Z:\home\Anastasiya\www\reg.php(25): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in

Comment: @Anastasiya не светите паролями :) + Вам на чистом английском написали "надо написать корректный запрос к БД. Свертись с мануалом"

Comment: @Anastasiya ктстати проблема в кавычках. В перечислении полей таблицы надо исползовать обратную одинарную ` , а не обычную '

Comment: Это шутка? Как сделать обратную одинарную кавычку, а не обычную?

Comment: символ ' и символ ` это не одно и то же

Answer (score 0):

практика программирования показывает следующее:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ('login','password')VALUES('$login','$password')";
echo $sql,PHP_EOL;
$mysqli -> query($sql);
```

echo $sql -- эту строчку всегда можно закоментирвоать или удалить, зато мы всегда сможем понять, какой запрос уходит в БД

так же полученный в выводе запрос можно выполнить в консоле mysql или PhpMyAdmin и увидеть ошибки

Comment: Александре, ты как всегда в тему )

Comment: Приятно видеть знакомые лица :; Пусть человек знакомиться с основами отладки.